# SQL function for FIND and MID as excel

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can someone help me how to write this in SQL?

I have excel formula to update one column using "K5" where "K5" is a column name.

```
=MID(K5,7,FIND(" ",K5,7)-7)
```

I want to apply this on my MS access table to update one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [`MID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/mid-function) in Access too.
Instead of `FIND()` Access provides the function [`INSTR()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/instr-function) with different syntax.
So use this:

```
= MID(columnname, 7, INSTR(7, columnname, ' ') - 7)
```

Comment: can you check it again? I tried this but now working.

Comment: .execute("UPDATE table SET column = MID(ITEM, 7, INSTR(7, ITEM, ' ') - 7)")

Comment: Yes it is checked. It returns the part of columnname starting from the 7th char up the next space.

Comment: Any guess where I am writing wrong? MID(colname, INSTR(colname, "in")+3, INSTR(INSTR(colname, "in")+3, colname, ' ') - INSTR(colname, "in")+3 for MID(K5, FIND("in",K5)+3,FIND("-",K5,FIND("-",K5)+2)-FIND("in",K5)-4)

Comment: I don't know what you want to do so I can't tell. Click the links of the 2 functions in my answer to check how they work.